# Select option needs to change

Tags: jquery-mobile, html-select

```
<select name="noofseats" data-native-menu="true">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4<option>                                             
</select>
```

In the above code I'm not supposed to use `data-native-menu` , but, if I don't use it I'm unable to select the options on the android screen.

I'm using jquerymobile framework.

Comment: Honestly, I cannot understand what you're asking.  Can you rephrase or give additional info?

Comment: this doesnt sound like static HTML?  Is there a server side scripting language involved? are oyu altering it with javascript after the facT?  you should specify that stuff, and tag your question in kind

Comment: Please provide a complete source code sample.

Comment: I literally laughed out loud. This has got to be the worst structured question I saw since I joined SO. No offense to the OP but... wow.

Comment: yes, @jon_darkstar, , I am getting the option values from Ajax call so needs to load into the framework.

Comment: yes, @khez, I am student, i did not used english for my daily life so it may literally wrong but i tried to say what my problem is...

Comment: @ayyappa didn't mean anything by it, as previously stated.

Comment: So this is an android/jquery mobile question? Can you give more details of the error?

Comment: damn, that edit took some brains out of me..phew! :\

Answer (score 0):

jquery mobile alpha4 uses native menus by default.

whatever the cost - update the jquery mobile version you use.

If the problem is that after an AJAX call you can't get options to display correctly - use `.page()` method.

Details here: http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/faq.html